# How to get average of input category in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The thing is I want to find average of value from a column with a condition of category, so whenever I put a category value into the cell I should get average of that category in another cell

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple QUERY formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Average

```
function average() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter Sheet Name");
  var avg = sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().reduce((a,c) => { a.sum += c;++a.cnt;return a;},{sum:0,cnt:0,av:function(){return this.sum/this.cnt}}).av();
  //Logger.log(avg);
  return avg;
}
```